# Script not working with not error message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

This is a range slider that uses this script http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider I have setup a JSbin http://jsbin.com/xelas/1/edit?html,css,js,output#C:L20 complete as there is a lot of code

I can't find any issue with this script as it was initially working and for some reason its not functioning and there is no error message at all.

### The script

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     $("#priceslider").sdcslider({
         range: true,
         orientation: 'horizontal',
         min: 170000,
         max: 500000,
         step: 10000,
         tooltip: 'hide',
         value: [170000, 500000]

     });
     $("#pricerange").text("$170.000 - $500.000");
     $("#priceslider").on('slide', function (slideEvt) {
         //console.log(slideEvt);
         $("#pricerange").text("$" + slideEvt.value[0] + " - $" + slideEvt.value[1]);
         var mi = slideEvt.value[0];
         var mx = slideEvt.value[1];
         filterPropertyPrice(mi, mx);
     });

     function filterPropertyPrice(minPrice, maxPrice) {
         $(".property").filter(function () {
             var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"));
             return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
         }).show();
     }
 });
```

### The HTML

```
<h4> Price Range: <span id="pricerange"></span></h4>
<input id="priceslider" class="sdcslider" type="text">
<div class="property" data-bedroom="3" data-price="300000">Property One</div>
<div class="property" data-bedroom="3" data-price="400000">Property Two</div>
<div class="property" data-bedroom="3" data-price="450000">Property Three</div>
<div class="property" data-bedroom="3" data-price="350000">Property Four</div>
<div class="property" data-bedroom="3" data-price="500000">Property Five</div>
```

Thanks & Regards
Said

Comment: Define `not working`.

Comment: What isn't working?  It seems ok to me.

Comment: @MelanciaUK its not filtering the properties when the sliders are slided

Comment: Only the values are changing but the properties are not filtering

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to hide them first

```
function filterPropertyPrice(minPrice, maxPrice) {
  $(".property") // select all the properties
                .hide() // hide all of them 
                .filter(function () {  // filter the ones that match the price
                    var price = parseInt($(this).data("price"));
                    return price >= minPrice && price <= maxPrice;
  }).show(); // show only the filtered ones
}
```

Comment: thanks heaps, that was it, I recall now that I had removed the hide to replace with fadeIn and totally overlooked reverting back to hide.